# Generate urls using T4MVC in a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

I am using t4mvc to generate links in my project. I would like to generate urls in a controller action, can this be done using t4mvc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes!

```
string url = Url.Action(MVC.Views.Index());
```

.. for example. You should get the same set of objects you get in your views, just access the `MVC` object and pass it to Url.Action().

Some more notes about using T4MVC in a controller action here: http://www.davidferguson.me.uk/Blogs/Post/strongly-typed-actions-views-and-controllers-with-t4mvc

Comment: Oops, This is not working in Controller and it just working in Razor :-(